# Separability of the (Frechet) space of continuous functions $C(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a completely regular space. Denote by $C_b(X)$ the Banach space of bounded and continuous functions on $X$ with the $sup$ norm. It is known that $C_b(X)$ is separable if and only if $X$ is a compact metric space.

Is there a similar result for the Frechet space $C(X)$ of continuous functions with the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets?

Comment: How are you making $C(X)$ a Fréchet space?  For instance, if $X$ is an uncountable discrete space, the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets is not metrizable...

Comment: Also, the correct statement about $C_b(X)$ is that $C_b(X)$ is separable iff $X$ is compact _and metrizable_ (or equivalently, compact and second-countable).

Comment: You are right, I forgot to write it. I edited my question. For the other point concerning the Frechet space, you can suppose that $X$ is $\sigma$-compact and locally compact. You can rephrase my question as to under which general hypotheses on the topological space $X$ the space $C(X)$ is a separable Frechet space with the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets.

Comment: Any reference for the reverse direction? ie separable implies space is compact and metrisable

Answer (score 1):

In the locally compact, $\sigma$-compact case, the required condition is that the compact sets be metrisable. This can be extended to a completely regular $k_R$-space which has a countable base for its compacta.  For example, the space of tempered distributions or, more generally, a Silva (locally convex) space.

Comment: What do you mean by "required condition". I don't get if you mean necessary or sufficient as a condition. Do you have an explicit reference for these results you mention?

Comment: I thought you were asking for a condition for your space to be a separable Fréchet space and so gave you it (for a completely regular space—-else the space $C(X)$ can collapse).  The $k_R$ condition is equivalent to this being complete, the countabiliy one to its being metrisable and then the metrisability of compacta to its separability.  Don‘t have a reference and doubt if there is one.